# Getting data from a ListView into an array

Tags: vb.net, listview, arrays

I have a ListView control on my form set up like this in details mode:

[image]

What I would like to do, is get all the values of the data cells when the user presses the `Delete booking` button.

So using the above example, my array would be filled with this data:

```
values(0) = "asd"
values(1) = "BS1"
values(2) = "asd"
values(3) = "21/04/2010"
values(4) = "2"
```

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim items As ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection = _
    Me.ManageList.SelectedItems
    Dim item As ListViewItem
    Dim values(0 To 4) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each item In items
        values(i) = item.SubItems(i).Text
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

But only `values(0)` gets filled with the first data cell of the selection (in this case "asd") and the rest of the array entries are blank. I have confirmed this with a breakpoint and checked the array entries myself.

I'm REALLY lost on this, and have been trying for about an hour now. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Also please note that there can only be one row selection at once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Costin is right about needing to iterate the subitems and if you're sure that there'll only be one selection iterating through the items just confuse things, I'd write it as:

```
  Dim values As New List(Of String)
  If ManageList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
     For Each item As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In ManageList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems
        values.Add(item.Text)
     Next
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you populate the list but for me it seems that you need to iterate the `item.Subitems` to get the values. I don't know VB but I think you can use a something like :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count
   values(i) = item.SubItems(i).Text
```

Comment: I populate it from a subroutine in my module. And I am iterating through the subitems aren't I? With the `item.SubItems(i).Text`.

Comment: In your code the i variable counts the items not the subitems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead..

```
    Dim values() As String

    If items.Count = 1 Then
        subitems = items(0).SubItems
        ReDim values(0 To subitems.Count - 1)
        For i As Integer = 0 To subitems.Count
            values(i) = subitems(i).Text
        Next
    Else
        Throw New Exception("boom")
    End If
```